# Remove duplicate words in a line with sed

Tags: sed

Purely academic, but it's frustrating me.

I want to correct this text:

```
there there are are multiple lexical errors in this line line
```

using sed. I've got this far:

```
sed 's/\([a-z][a-z]*[ ,\n][ ,\n]*\)\1/\1/g' < file.text
```

It corrects everything except the final doubled up words!

```
there are multiple lexical errors in this line line
```

Can a sed guru please explain why the above doesn't deal with the words at the end?

Comment: N.B. RE - `[ ,\n]` sed uses the `\n` as a line delimiter. So unless you insert `\n`'s into the pattern space, you will never encounter them after having read a line into the pattern space.

Answer (score 11):

This is because in the last case (`line`) your regex memory 1 will have `line` (line followed by a space) in it and you are searching for its repetition. Since there is not space after the last `line` the match fails.

To fix this add a space after the ending word `line`.

Alternatively you can change the regex to:

```
sed -e 's/\b\([a-z]\+\)[ ,\n]\1/\1/g'
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/vOYdc)